# mongoose duplicate key error for deleted property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I deleted a property called 'userName' from my mongoose schema that was set to be unique, and now it seems that the property is still holding on to my documents. I'm getting a duplicate key error when trying to add a new document to the database because it says that the there already exists a document with 'userName' set to null.

Does anyone know how to fix this without creating a new db?

Comment: How did you delete the property? Any chance that it is set to null instead?

Comment: I just removed the property from my schema definition, I'm guessing this was wrong..

Comment: Removing from schema is not enough. Try the [`$unset `](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator